# **Warning**: Use of undefined constant HTTP_HOST] in PHP

Tags: php

I am encountering a bug in the Following code (which is the base file for an Gmod loading screen).

I am currently moving the PHP site from one webserver to a self hosted one. Its running Nginx what is pointing to PHP. To the problem:
If I am just loading it on the new website, I get the following error:

**Warning**: Use of undefined constant HTTP_HOST - assumed 'HTTP_HOST' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in C:\Websites\Readling\index.php on line 13
**Warning**: Use of undefined constant REQUEST_URI - assumed 'REQUEST_URI' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in C:\Websites\Readling\index.php on line 13

After doing the in the message wanted think the Website don't load. The same goes for deactivating error reports. I don't know what is wrong and I don't have much knowledge about PHP. I already tried multiple PHP versions but nothing helped. I just want that it works like on the other webserver [WITHOUT CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFRAn.jpg) [Complete Source Code](https://mega.nz/file/XVIEGQKA#Q0MtDxbxeP1Tq9J9loPUmkAzKYUuQapGalLOdUxYOws)

If you have any Questions for Debug Infos etc. please explain me where i can find it. I dont have that much clue in that area (which is probably the reason why my old question was closed) Thanks vor your Time and have a great Day :)

```
    <?php
ini_set( "display_errors", 1);
// A Steam API Key is required so as to be able to contact steam and get a users profile image and name
// You can get a Steam API Key by visiting http://steamcommunity.com/dev/apikey
// Don't worry about the web address, it won't have any effect so just type in any web site
// Once you have your steam API Key simply paste the key below. (Make sure the quotation marks are still there or else it won't work)
$SteamAPIKey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    
$error_url = 'http://' . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$error_url_test = $error_url . '?steamid=76561198000430367';
$error_url_server = $error_url . '?steamid=%s';

if (!isset($_GET["steamid"])) {
    die("Woops, you don't seem to be using the correct extension in the address bar to get the loading screen to work.<br />
    Please make sure it has the correct extension it should have ?steamid= at the end of it and look something like this: www.yourdomain.com/loading/index.php?steamid=%s<br /><br />

    You can use the link below which will automatically add a test steam id to see if your loading screen is configured properly<br />
    <a href='$error_url_test'>$error_url_test</a><br /><br />
    
    When setting your loading url please make sure you set the steam id to %s as shown in the link below<br />
    <a href='$error_url_server'>$error_url_server</a>
    
    ");
}

$steamid64 = $_GET["steamid"];

$url = "http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=" . $SteamAPIKey . "&steamids=" . $steamid64;
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$table2 = json_decode($json, true);
$table = $table2["response"]["players"][0];

?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
    <!-- Hello, your reading the source code for the server load page -->
    <!-- Created by CaptainMcMarcus for CoderHire -->
    <!-- This is the HTML code below and is safe to edit to your needs -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <meta name="description" content="Wilkommen - Loading..." /> <!-- Webpage Description --> 
    <title>Hofload</title> <!-- Webpage Title -->
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> <!-- Links to the Stylesheet -->
    <link href="./colour.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> <!-- Links to the Stylesheet for main colours -->
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script><!-- Link to jquery so we can do cool stuff -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/cycle.js"></script><!-- For Rotating Backgrounds -->
    
    <script type="text/javascript"><!-- Script to center content -->
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //Changes volume of song. 0.5=50% volume
        $('.audio').prop("volume", 0.9);
            
        //Perfectly centers content to the middle of the screen both vertically and horizontally
        $(window).resize(function(){
              $('.core-wrapper').css({
               position:'absolute',
               left: ($(window).width() 
                 - $('.core-wrapper').outerWidth())/2,
               top: ($(window).height() 
                 - $('.core-wrapper').outerHeight())/2
              });   
        });
        
        
        //Lets get those backgrounds moving
        $('#background-scroll').cycle({ 
            fx: 'fade',
            pause: 0, 
            speed: 4500, //Time to fade into the next image [in milliseconds]
            timeout: 3500  //Time spent on image [in milliseconds]
        });     
        //Lets get those pictures moving
        $('#img-scroll').cycle({ 
            fx: 'fade',
            pause: 0, 
            speed: 4500, //Time to fade into the next image [in milliseconds]
            timeout: 2500  //Time spent on image [in milliseconds]
        });
        // Initiate center function
        $(window).resize();
    });
    </script>
    

    </head>
    
    <body>
    
    <div id="background-scroll"><!-- Add Backgrounds so we can have multiple ones -->
        <!-- IF YOU NEED LESS BACKGROUNDS JUST REMOVE THEM OUT OF THE LIST -->
        <!-- TO ADD EXTRA BACKGROUNDS YOU NEED TO MODIFY THE STYLESHEET [ADVANCED USERS ONLY] -->
        <div id="bg1"></div><!-- BG 1 -->
        <div id="bg2"></div><!-- BG 2 -->
        <div id="bg3"></div><!-- BG 3 -->
        <div id="bg4"></div><!-- BG 4 -->
        <div id="bg5"></div><!-- BG 5 -->
        <div id="bg6"></div><!-- BG 6 -->
        <div id="bg7"></div><!-- BG 7 -->   
        <div id="bg8"></div>
        <div id="bg9"></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="core-wrapper"><!-- Opens the wrapper so we can contain and center everything -->
        
        <img src="images/logo.png" width="960" height="120" alt="Your Logo" /><!-- This adds in the logo, simply change logo.png to make this look different -->
    
        <div id="left-items"><!-- Opens the wrapper for the left content, there isn't really much to change on the left side as it's dynamic -->
    
            <?php
                //PHP Code for the avatar display, it's probably best to leave this section alone
                echo "<div id=\"profile-wrap\">";
                    
                    //Add in the players avatar
                    echo "<div id=\"profile-top\">";
                        echo "<div id=\"avatarimg\">";
                            echo "<img src=\"" . $table["avatarfull"] . "\" />";
                        echo "</div>";
                    echo "</div>";
                    
                    //Adds in the players name
                    echo "<div id=\"profile-bottom\">";
                        echo "<p>" . $table["personaname"] . "</p>";
                    echo "</div>";
                    
                echo "</div>";
            ?>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            
            <!--<li><img src="images/asuna.png" alt="Asuna SAO" name="asuna" style="position:absolute;top:50px;left:180px;z-index:-1;width:350px;height:350px;"/></li>-->
            <div class="title server">
                <h2>Hof Lan</h2><!-- Adds in the server title, you can change the text to be whatever you would like -->
            </div>
            
            <!-- Lets get the server Details in here -->
            <ul id="server-list">
                
                <li><img src="images/server-name.png" alt="Server Name" /> <span id="s-name">Server Name</span></li><!-- Dynamically adds the server name -->
                <li><img src="images/server-mode.png" alt="Game Mode" /> <span id="s-mode">Server Game Mode</span></li><!-- Dynamically adds game mode name -->
                <li><img src="images/server-map.png" alt="Map Name" /> <span id="s-map">Server Map Name</span></li><!-- Dynamically adds map name -->
            <div id="img-scroll"><!-- Add Backgrounds so we can have multiple ones -->
                <!-- IF YOU NEED LESS BACKGROUNDS JUST REMOVE THEM OUT OF THE LIST -->
                <!-- TO ADD EXTRA BACKGROUNDS YOU NEED TO MODIFY THE STYLESHEET [ADVANCED USERS ONLY] -->   

            </div>
            
            </ul>
            
        </div><!-- Close The Wrapper for the Left Items -->
        
        <div id="right-items"><!-- Open wrapper for the items on the right -->
            
            <div class="title">
                <h2>Regeln</h2><!-- Adds in the rules title, you can change the text to be whatever you would like -->
            </div>
            
            <!-- Let's add in all the rules, the number inside the <span></span> tags will appear in a brighter colored box  -->
            <ul id="rules">
                <li><span>1</span> Kein RDMen</li>
                <li><span>2</span> Fair Play bitte</li>
                <li><span>3</span> New Live regel bezogen auf Maps.</li>
                <li><span>4</span> Nicht Beleidigen</li>
                <li><span>5</span> Propkillen erlaubt.</li>
                <li><span>6</span> Nicht  DDossen.</li>
                <li><span>7</span> Kein Spamen</li>
                <li><span>8</span> Kein Bug Ambusing</li>
                <li><span>9</span> Nicht unnötig Trollen </li>

            </ul>
            <!--<li><img src="images/mirai.png" alt="Mirai Kyoukai no Kanata" name="mirai" style="position:absolute;top:0px;right:0px;z-index:-1;width:350px;height:350px;"/></li>-->
        </div><!-- This close the right content wrapper -->
        
        <div class="clear"></div><!-- This clears things up so that we can vertically align things correctly -->
 <?php
    
    $musiclist = [
    1 => "music/1.ogg",
    2 => "music/2.ogg",
    3 => "music/3.ogg",
    4 => "music/4.ogg",
    5 => "music/5.ogg",
    6 => "music/6.ogg",
    7 => "music/7.ogg",
    8 => "music/8.ogg",
    9 => "music/9.ogg",
    10 => "music/10.ogg",
    11 => "music/11.ogg",
    12 => "music/12.ogg",
    13 => "music/13.ogg",
    14 => "music/14.ogg",
    15 => "music/15.ogg",
    16 => "music/16.ogg",
    17 => "music/17.ogg",
    18 => "music/18.ogg",
    19 => "music/19.ogg",
    20 => "music/20.ogg",
    21 => "music/21.ogg",
    22 => "music/22.ogg",
    23 => "music/23.ogg",
    24 => "music/24.ogg",
    25 => "music/25.ogg",
    26 => "music/26.ogg",
    


    ];
    $musicname = [
    1 => "Kerstin Ott & Helene Fischer - Regenbogenfarben",
    2 => "Barack Obama - 1999",
    3 => "My Little Pony - Theme Song",
    4 => "Puhdys - Dezembertage",
    5 => "SAINt JHN - Roses",
    6 => "Thomas the Tank engine - Theme song",
    7 => "The White Stripes & Gabe Prusa - Seven Nation Army (Glitch Mob Remix)",
    8 => "The 4Head - Ocean Man Voice Crack",
    9 => "Pink Fonk - Baby Shark EARRAPE",
    10 => "Mr. Rucki Peng - Weinachten am Altschauerberg (feat. Rainer)",
    11 => "Nintendo - Wii Sports Theme",
    12 => "Tim Tupet - Tote Enten",
    13 => "Hype Awards - BERLIN WAS GEHT AB",
    14 => "Nickelodeon - Krusty Krab Trap Mix",
    15 => "Erik Follestad og Linni Meister - Juletragedien",
    16 => "Bibi und Tina Theme - Remix",
    17 => "Möhre - 20 Zentimeter",
    18 => "Dschingis Kahn - Moskau (Remix)",
    19 => "Goodybe Moonman - Rick and Morty",
    20 => "Fortnite Anthem (Danke Felix <3)",
    21 => "Ikke Hüftgold - Salz auf die Eier",
    22 => "Snob Livees Matter - Peter Smits",
    23 => "Helikopter 117 - Tobee/ Extreme Sound",
    24 => "Da Coconut Nut (Coconut Song) - Jeff Lau",
    25 => "Irgendwelche Chinesen - Chinese Song",
    26 => "Woods Tune - Santa Woodie"
    ];
    $rand = rand(1,sizeof($musiclist));
    
    echo '<audio id="bgmusic" class="audio" autoplay autobuffer="autobuffer" volume="0.9">';
        echo '<source src='.$musiclist[$rand].' type="audio/ogg">';
    echo '</audio>' ;
    echo '<div id="songbg"><h3 id="mc"> Music: </h3><h4 id="song">'.$musicname[$rand].'</div>';

 ?>       
        <!-- This adds in the progress bar -->
        <div id="bar">
            <div id="bar-width" style="width: 0%;"></div>
        </div>
        
        <!-- This adds in the progress percentage bar -->
        <div id="percentage">
            <p></p>
        </div>
        
        <!-- This adds the current item being downloaded, we use the word connecting by default because if we don't download anything then it won't change -->
        <div id="download-item">
            <p>Connecting...</p>
        </div>
    
    
    
    <!-- MUSIC SCRIPT -->
    <!-- To activate simply delete the comment tags and replace music.mp3 with the path to your sound file. -->
    <!-- Adding copyrighted music is illegal as you will be redistributing from the server this is hosted from, this means that you will be held liable -->
    
    <!--
    <audio class="audio" autoplay autobuffer="autobuffer">
        <source src="music.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    </audio>
 -->
 
    </div><!-- now we close the core wrapper to keep everything nicely contained and in the middle -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/main.js"></script><!-- Script to get downloads, map, players, game mode and sort out the loading bar -->

    </body><!-- Closes off the HTML Document -->
</html>
```

Comment: The warnings are not triggered by the code you posted. Search for code that uses `HTTP_HOST` as is, not quoted and you'll find the cause.

Comment: The cause and the solution for this warnings are explained in the [PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.syntax.php).

Comment: What does line 13 in your index.php look like? The error doesn't match the code you've posted

Comment: Make sure on line 13 of index.php they are `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` and not `$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]`, missing quotes maybe?

Comment: @Bosman if i am doing that, the Page wont load any css

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson you can see the Full code in the linked Sourcecode Zip

Comment: Please add all relevant code into the question itself. I'm not going to download and extract a zip file that comes from some unknown person online.The question need to contain all information/code on it's own. If not, the question will not be as helpful for future visitors when that link with the file expires.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson The Link Wont expire. I have an Mega account for Nearly 2 Years and never Deleted any file for Questions and Public Downloads

Comment: _"The Link Wont expire"_ -  Anything can happen with sites. It could be as simple as the site being down while someone reads this question (yes, it can happen). All relevant code needs to be in the question itself. That's how this site works. And I doubt many people are interested of downloading and extract a zip file from some random person online. You're basically asking people to jump through hoops just to be able to help you. The less road blocks you put up, the more people will be inclined to help.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson How Can i implement the code that the syntax of the diffrent files is right?

Comment: @Bossman Worked for me. I forgot to add '' and now it is fine.